# Java HashMap sometimes returning wrong value in some threads

Tags: java, hashmap

**Update:** It was a static buried deep in some code where it was used for just a couple of instructions. Thank you all for the suggestions.

We are not using one HashMap across threads (yes that is bad for many reasons). Each thread has its own HashMap.

We have a class that extends from Thread. In Thread.run() we create a HashMap, set a key/value pair in it, and pass that HashMap to a method. That method retrieves the value from the HashMap, inserts it into a string, and returns the string.

Sometimes the returned string has a different value (still in Thread.run()). This only occurs on hardware with 3+ physical cores. And it has only happened twice (before we added logging to help us find exactly what is going on of course).

Any idea why this would occur.

Update: here's the full code. The ProcessTxt is what pulls the value from the HashMap and puts it in the string.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import net.windward.datasource.dom4j.Dom4jDataSource;
import net.windward.xmlreport.ProcessReport;
import net.windward.xmlreport.ProcessTxt;

/**
 * Test calling from multiple threads
 */
public class TestThreads extends TestCase {

    private static String path = ".";

    // JUnit stuff
    public TestThreads(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    // Get logging going - called before any tests run
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        ProcessReport.init();
    }

    // this is not necessary - called after any tests are run
    protected void tearDown() {
    }

    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 100;

    private boolean hadWithVarError = false;


    /**
     * Test that each thread has unique variables.
     */
    public void testRunReportsWithVariables() throws Exception {

        // run 10 threads
        ReportThreadWithVariables[] th = new ReportThreadWithVariables[NUM_THREADS];
        for (int ind = 0; ind < NUM_THREADS; ind++) {
            th[ind] = new ReportThreadWithVariables(this, ind);
            th[ind].setName("Run " + ind);
        }
        for (int ind = 0; ind < NUM_THREADS; ind++)
            th[ind].start();

        boolean allDone = false;
        while (!allDone) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            allDone = true;
            for (int ind = 0; ind < NUM_THREADS; ind++)
                if (th[ind].isAlive())
                    allDone = false;
        }

        assertTrue(!hadWithVarError);
    }

    public static class ReportThreadWithVariables extends Thread {

        private TestThreads obj;
        private int num;

        public ReportThreadWithVariables(TestThreads tt, int num) {
            obj = tt;
            this.num = num;
        }

        public void run() {

            try{
                System.out.println("starting " + num);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ProcessTxt pt = new ProcessTxt(new FileInputStream(new File(path, "Thread_Test.docx")), out);

                pt.processSetup();

                // don't use order1.xml, but need a datasource.
                Dom4jDataSource datasource = new Dom4jDataSource(new FileInputStream(new File(path, "order1.xml")));
                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                map.put("num", new Integer(num));
                datasource.setMap(map);
                pt.processData(datasource, "");

                pt.processComplete();
                String result = out.toString().trim();
                System.out.println("complete " + num + ", result = " + result);

                String expected = "Number: " + num;
                if (!result.equals( expected ))
                    obj.hadWithVarError = true;
                assertEquals(expected, result);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                obj.hadWithVarError = true;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

(edit to format code)

Comment: What is the key? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would *really* help...

Comment: What type the value is could also be relevant. Is it possible that the values contain an object that is referenced and later modified elsewhere?

Comment: The code you posted is not terribly well written.  You might find that doing general code cleanup fixes your problem.  For example even your handling of hadWithVarError is racey... it "sounds like it should work" but due to the way the Java Memory Model is specified you must properly synchronize (or mark volatile) even simple boolean fields.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something unit test is wrong. You never write to ByteArrayOutputStream 'out', but read 'result' from it

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of code and based solely on what has been written I am going to hypothesize that something is `static`. That is, somewhere along the line a static member is being stored to/written from.

Comment: That was the first thing we looked for - nothing is static. Also, this very rarely happens - we have to run for about 4 minutes on a 4 core system to get this. And on a 2 core system it never happens. I'll post code.

Answer (score 0):

num is not mutable and the other variables (string, map) are local so ReportThreadWithVariables looks thread safe. It seems to me that the problem is in the calls to external objects rather than what you posted.
Are the classes you use documented as Thread Safe?

For exampel, the [javadoc of the processData method](http://www.windwardreports.com/javadoc/net/windward/xmlreport/ProcessReport.html#processData%28net.windward.datasource.DataSourceProvider,%20java.lang.String%29) states that it should not be called multiple times for the same datasource which you seem to be doing (same file name).

ps: (not related) you could use a CountDownLatch instead of the while loop.